# Подвисает браузер при отправке больших файлов на сервер. AJAX, PHP, JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, файлы, formdata

Возникла проблема при отправке больших данных на сервер. Уже не знаю, что делать.
При отправке маленьких файлов - всё проходит незаметно почти.
При отправке объемных файлов, браузер начинает зависать. Файл та отправится, но работать в браузере во время отправки невозможно.

Причину я понимаю. Отправка файла происходит в основном потоке.
Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как можно сделать, чтобы при отправке больших файлов браузер не затормаживал свою работу хотяб на других сайтах.

```
    function UploadFileIntoFileManager(button_obj, form_obj)
{
    // https://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-progress-bar-indikator-protsessa-zagruzki.html

    CreateGeneralLoadingModalBox('Файловое хранилище', 'Подождите, идет загрузка файла...<br>Загружено 0%');
    OpenGeneralLoadingModalBox();

    var file_data = $('#file-upload').prop('files')[0];

    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('action', 'UploadFileIntoFileManager'); 
    form_data.append('file', file_data); 

    $(form_obj).find('input[type=file]').prop('value', ''); // Очистка данных по файлу в кнопке

    var LastPercent = 0;

    $.ajax({
        type: form_obj.getAttribute('method'),
        url: form_obj.getAttribute('action'),
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        beforeSend:function()
        {

        },
        xhr: function(){
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr(); // получаем объект XMLHttpRequest
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt){ // добавляем обработчик события progress (onprogress)
              if(evt.lengthComputable) { // если известно количество байт
                // высчитываем процент загруженного
                var percentComplete = Math.ceil(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
                // устанавливаем значение в атрибут value тега <progress>
                // и это же значение альтернативным текстом для браузеров, не поддерживающих <progress>
                $('.exit-but, .ex').click( function(){
                    CloseAndDestroyGeneralLoadingModalBox(true);
                    xhr.abort();
                    return false;
                });
                if(LastPercent !== percentComplete)
                {
                    LastPercent = percentComplete;
                    UpdateGeneralLoadingModalBoxContentTitle('Подождите, идет загрузка файла...<br>Загружено '+percentComplete+'%');
                }
              }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            CloseAndDestroyGeneralLoadingModalBox(true);

            /*if(data['ReturnCode'] === false)
            {
                CreateGeneralFalseModalBox('Файловое хранилище', 'Возникла ошибка', data['ReturnMessage'], 'ок');
                OpenGeneralFalseModalBox();
                return false;
            }
            else if(data['ReturnCode'] === true)
            {
                document.location.reload(true);
                return true;
            }*/
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            CloseAndDestroyGeneralLoadingModalBox(true);

            CreateGeneralFalseModalBox('Файловое хранилище','Сервер не отвечает','Пожалуйста, попробуйте позже','ок');
            OpenGeneralFalseModalBox();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Приведенный код не должен тормозить. Может, у вас тормозит что-то другое?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Нет. При запуске кода начинает тормозить весь браузер. Проблема не в ноуте, 100%.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что тормозит какой-то другой участок кода. Потому что в приведенном коде тормозов быть не должно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможные варианты решения:
1. Попробовать перевести ajax в синхронный режим `async:false`
2. Открыть перед отправкой файла диспетчер вкладок браузера на chorme это делается с помощью комбинаций клавиш shift+esc и посмотреть какая вкладка нагружает по оперативной памяти и ЦПУ комп при отправки файла и уже от этого что то думать, например если вы грузите файл размером 5 гигабайт посмотреть на сколько раздуется по оперативной памяти вкладка с отправкой файла, скорее всего копия файла ложится в оперативную память а так как у вас на компе ее мало, браузер начинает тормозить.
3. Использовать какую ни будь библиотеку для загрузки файлов на сервер например `DropZone` загружал с ее помощью файлы размером гигабайт и все отлично работало, так как в таких библиотеках файлы отправляются частями на сервер. Набор библиотек смотреть [тут](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=2200)

Comment: Как поможет перевод ajax в синхронный режим?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko синхронный режим покажет тормозит код загрузки файла или код исполняемый далее

Comment: Интересный подход)) А можете рассказать поподробнее про этот способ? Можно даже в ответе - будет полезно всем!

Comment: Как мы знаем ajax по умолчанию выполняется асинхронно, значит когда мы начали загрузку файла js продолжил выполнение и не будет ждать завершения загрузки. Если мы переведем ajax в синхронный режим и снова попробуем загрузить файл, и ноут не будет тормозить значит дело было в коде который выполняется далее после ajax а если все равно будет тормозить значит дело в ajax.

Comment: Ну, если переведем в синхронный режим, то он по любому будет тормозить. Он же будет ждать ответа сервера! В каком случае он не будет тормозить в синхронном режиме?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko ну так мы проверяем не скорость работы скрипта, а будет тормозить ноут или нет, мы отслеживаем код который выполняется после ajax т.е в момент выполнения ajax будет ли тормозить код, так узнаем причину, все таки торозит комп из за ajax или из за кода выполняющегося после ajax